# Filter for one specific node in JSON, show direct parents and all children

Tags: javascript, json

Given the following JSON object;

```
const data = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Node 1", "children": [
            { "id": 3, "name": "Node 1.1", "children": [
                    { "id": 6, "name": "Node 1.1.1", "children": [
                            { "id": 12, "name": "Node 1.1.1.1", "children": [] }
                        ]
                    },
                    { "id": 7, "name": "Node 1.1.2", "children": [
                            { "id": 13, "name": "Node 1.1.2.1", "children": [] }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            { "id": 4, "name": "Node 1.2", "children": [
                { "id": 8, "name": "Node 1.2.1", "children": [] },
                { "id": 9, "name": "Node 1.2.2", "children": [
                        { "id": 14, "name": "Node 1.2.2.1", "children": [] },
                        { "id": 15, "name": "Node 1.2.2.2", "children": [] }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Node 2", "children": [
            { "id": 5, "name": "Node 2.1", "children": [
                    { "id": 10, "name": "Node 2.1.1", "children": [] },
                    { "id": 11, "name": "Node 2.1.2", "children": [
                            { "id": 16, "name": "Node 2.1.2.1", "children": [] }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I want to be able to find a specific node by ID and once that node is found get its direct parents and all children. For example, if I want to find the node with ID 9 (Node 1.2.2), I want it to return `Node 1`, `Node 1.2`, `Node 1.2.2` and its children, and ignore everything else. I've got this partially working with this `findById` function;

```
findById(data, id)
{
    let node = '';
    data.some((currentNode) => {
        return node = id === currentNode.id ? currentNode : this.findById(currentNode.children, id);
    });
    return node;
}
```

which is called like this;

```
this.data = [this.findById(this.data, id)];
```

but it doesn't do exactly what I want. It finds the correct node (so in this case 1.2.2) and its children (1.2.2.1 and 1.2.2.2), but not its direct parents (1.2 and 1). How could I change the `findById` function to also include the direct parents?

The desired output would be;

```
const found = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Node 1", "children": [
            { "id": 4, "name": "Node 1.2", "children": [
                    { "id": 9, "name": "Node 1.2.2", "children": [
                            { "id": 14, "name": "Node 1.2.2.1", "children": [] },
                            { "id": 15, "name": "Node 1.2.2.2", "children": [] }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a _JSON Object_ - JSON is always a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to store the result of your recursive function. To do this separate your ternary into an if else like below:

```js
function findById(data, id) {
    let node = null;

    data.some((currentNode) => {
        if (id === currentNode.id) {
            return node = [currentNode];
        }

        const inItsTree = findById(currentNode.children, id);
        if (inItsTree) {
            return node = [{ ...currentNode, children: inItsTree }];
        }
    });

    return node;
}

const data = [{"id":1,"name":"Node 1","children":[{"id":3,"name":"Node 1.1","children":[{"id":6,"name":"Node 1.1.1","children":[{"id":12,"name":"Node 1.1.1.1","children":[]}]},{"id":7,"name":"Node 1.1.2","children":[{"id":13,"name":"Node 1.1.2.1","children":[]}]}]},{"id":4,"name":"Node 1.2","children":[{"id":8,"name":"Node 1.2.1","children":[]},{"id":9,"name":"Node 1.2.2","children":[{"id":14,"name":"Node 1.2.2.1","children":[]},{"id":15,"name":"Node 1.2.2.2","children":[]}]}]}]},{"id":2,"name":"Node 2","children":[{"id":5,"name":"Node 2.1","children":[{"id":10,"name":"Node 2.1.1","children":[]},{"id":11,"name":"Node 2.1.2","children":[{"id":16,"name":"Node 2.1.2.1","children":[]}]}]}]}];

console.log(findById(data, 9));
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want, just have to make it work with the rest of my code now, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The first question is, is this the correct data structure? Can you implement this in a Linked List? If so, you can have specific references to grandparent nodes, parent nodes. If the data is relatively small, the search time is linear and insertion and deletion is linear.

```
class Node {
  constructor(value){
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
    this.children = [];
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.size = 0
    }

  insert(value) {
    let node = new Node(value);
    if(!this.head) {
      this.head = node;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = node;
    }
    this.tail = node;
    this.size++;
  }

  findNode(value) {
    let node = this.head;
    while(!!node) {
      if(node.value === value){
        return node;
      }
      node = node.next;
    }
    return `no node with ${value} found`
  }

  forEach(callback) {
    let node = this.head;
    while(!!node) {
      callback(node.value);
      node = node.next;
    }
  }

  print() {
    if(!this.head) {
      return null
    } else {
      let node = this.head;
      while(!!node){
        console.log(node.value);
        node = node.next
      }
    }
```

Comment: *"deletion is constant time"* - that sounds incorrect, nor has it been demonstrated in your answer. Maybe just leave that part out?

Comment: @user633183, you are correct, linear when finding by id.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your findById method as:

```
function findById(data, id, parent)
{
    let node = '';
    data.some((currentNode) => {
      if(id === currentNode.id) {
        node = currentNode;
      } else {
        parent.push(currentNode); // track parent node
        node = this.findById(currentNode.children, id, parent);
      }
      return node;
    });
    return {node: node, parent: parent};
}

this.data = [this.findById(this.data, 6, [])];

console.log(this.data[0].node); // will give you current node with children
console.log(this.data[0].parent); // will give you array of parents node
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so here is a solution using functional style -

```
// identity : 'a -> 'a
const identity = x =>
  x

// findById : (number, node array) -> node?
const findById = (q = 0, [ n, ...more ], exit = identity) =>
  n === undefined
    ? false
    : findById1 (q, n, exit)
      || findById (q, more, exit)

// findById1 : (number, node) -> node?
const findById1 = (q = 0, n = {}, exit = identity) =>
  n.id === q
    ? exit (n)
    : findById (q, n.children, r =>
        exit ({...n, children: [ r ] })
      )
```

It works like this -

```
findById (9, data)
// { id: 1, name: "Node 1", children: [
//   { id: 4, name: "Node 1.2", children: [
//     { id: 9, name: "Node 1.2.2", children: [
//         { id: 14, name: "Node 1.2.2.1", children: [] },
//         { id: 15, name: "Node 1.2.2.2", children: [] }
//     ]}
//   ]}
// ]}
```

When an id cannot be found, `false` is returned -

```
findById (99, data)
// false
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const findById = (q = 0, [ n, ...more ], exit = identity) =>
  n === undefined
    ? false
    : findById1 (q, n, exit)
      || findById (q, more, exit)

const findById1 = (q = 0, n = {}, exit = identity) =>
  n.id === q
    ? exit (n)
    : findById (q, n.children, r =>
        exit ({...n, children: [ r ] })
      )

const data =
  [{id:1, name:"Node 1", children:[{id:3, name:"Node 1.1", children:[{id:6, name:"Node 1.1.1", children:[{id:12, name:"Node 1.1.1.1", children:[]}]},{id:7, name:"Node 1.1.2", children:[{id:13, name:"Node 1.1.2.1", children:[]}]}]},{id:4, name:"Node 1.2", children:[{id:8, name:"Node 1.2.1", children:[]},{id:9, name:"Node 1.2.2", children:[{id:14, name:"Node 1.2.2.1", children:[]},{id:15, name:"Node 1.2.2.2", children:[]}]}]}]},{id:2, name:"Node 2", children:[{id:5, name:"Node 2.1", children:[{id:10, name:"Node 2.1.1", children:[]},{id:11, name:"Node 2.1.2", children:[{id:16, name:"Node 2.1.2.1", children:[]}]}]}]}]

console.log (findById (9, data))
// { id: 1, name: "Node 1", children: [
//   { id: 4, name: "Node 1.2", children: [
//     { id: 9, name: "Node 1.2.2", children: [
//         { id: 14, name: "Node 1.2.2.1", children: [] },
//         { id: 15, name: "Node 1.2.2.2", children: [] }
//     ]}
//   ]}
// ]}

console.log (findById (99, data))
// false
```

---

Continuation-passing style leaks the `exit` param in the function's interface. Using a helper function, we can create an api that matches your original -

```
// export findById : (number, node array) -> node? 
const findById = (q = 0, nodes = []) =>
  findAny (q, nodes, identity)

// private
const findAny = (q, [ node, ...more ], exit) =>
  node === undefined
    ? false
    : find1 (q, node, exit)
      || findAny (q, more, exit)

// private
const find1 = (q, node, exit) =>
  node.id === q
    ? exit (node)
    : findAny (q, node.children, r =>
        exit ({...node, children: [ r ] })
      )
```

---

Lastly, we could modify our original implementation to create a higher-order `findBy`, which instead of taking an `id` input, it accepts a function similar to `Array.prototype.find` -

```
// export findBy : ('node -> bool, node array) -> node?
const findBy = (f = identity, nodes = []) =>
  findAny (f, nodes, identity)

// private
const findAny = (f, [ node, ...more ], exit) =>
  node === undefined
    ? false
    : find1 (f, node, exit)
      || findAny (f, more, exit)

// private
const find1 = (f, node, exit) =>
  f (node)
    ? exit (node)
    : findAny (f, node.children, r =>
        exit ({...node, children: [ r ] })
      )
```

More specific functions like `findById` and `findByName` can easily be implemented by specialising `findBy` -

```
// export findById : (number, node array) -> node? 
const findById = (q = 0, nodes = []) =>
  findBy (n => n.id === q, nodes, identity)

// export findByName : (string, node array) -> node? 
const findByName = (q = "", nodes = []) =>
  findBy (n => n.name === q, nodes, identity)
```

Or you can find by any arbitrary thing -

```
findBy (node => node.id > 100 && node.name.length < 20, data)
// ...
```

Hopefully this begins to illustrate some of the advantages of functional style.